# Contar valores en un campo según array

Tags: sql, google-chart-api

tengo el siguiente inconveniente necesito contar los valores de un campo llamado "Tipo", en una tabla llamada movilesu, el problema es que debo contar solo los valores que defino en un array denominado $tipos(). No me sale la consulta porque necesito graficarlo con goolge chart y debo obtener la cantidad para cada valor definido en el array. Adjunto codigo de  la consulta ..Perdon como cargo la función directamente cuando se abre la pagina. desde ya muchas gracias

```
 <?php
$tipos = array('', 'Auto', 'Camion Volcador', 'Camion Prensa', 'Camion Regador', 'Camioneta furgon', 'Camioneta Pick up', 'Maquina Vial', 'Motocarga', 'Motocicleta');

for ($x = 1; $x < sizeof($tipos); $x = $x + 1) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Tipo) as tipos  from movilesu where Id_condicion = 1 group by '$tipos[$x]' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $cantidad[$x] = $cantidad[$x] + $row['tipos'];
    }

}

var_dump($cantidad[$x]);
```

// Código para la grafica Google chart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load google charts
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values

    function drawChart()
    {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Tipo','Tipos de móviles', {role: 'annotation'}],
       <?php
    
    for ($x = 1; $x < sizeof($tipos); $x = $x + 1) {
    
        ?>
         ['<?php echo $tipos[$x]; ?>', <?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>,<?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>],
       <?php }?>
    
       ]);
    
     var options = {
      title:' Tipos de moviles'
        ,seriesType: 'bars'
        ,series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
        ,legend:{position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16}}
    
      ,width:"100%"
      ,height: 450
    
    };
    
                // Instantiate and draw the chart.
                var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
              }
    
              $(window).resize(function(){
    
                drawChart();
    
              });
    
    
    
            </script>
```

// reedite el código y obtengo la siguiente gráfica

[image: Solo me trae la cantidad total "221" de tipos, que cumplen con la condición =1 pero no muestra la cantidad por tipos]

Answer (score 0):

logre resolver el problema, simplemente cambie la consulta e iguale en la condición where el campo Tipo al array $tipo[$x]. No se puede agrupar por los elementos del array ..Adjunto código

```
    <?php
$tipos = array('', 'Auto', 'Camion Volcador', 'Camion Prensa', 'Camion Regador', 'Camioneta furgon', 'Camioneta Pick up', 'Maquina Vial', 'Motocarga', 'Motocicleta');

for ($x = 1; $x < sizeof($tipos); $x = $x + 1) {
    $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(Tipo) as tipos  from movilesu where Id_condicion = 1 and Tipo = '$tipos[$x]' ");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $cantidad[$x] = $cantidad[$x] + $row['tipos'];
    }

}
```

// el código de la grafica es el mismo y tambien se puede consultar en la web

[image: Los datos los controlé con la bd y son los mismos que el gráfico]